# PHP Cache page unless content has changed?

Tags: php, caching

Cant seem to find a good answer to this, i want to cache my php page that reads data in from SQL DB, however, if the data's changed then reload and make a new cache?

Users can add new items to the db all the time and as such it would need to be re cached every time a user is added, however the db is being called every single time someone wants to get the data, even when no new values have been added? How can i eliminate such a problem?

```
if (file_exists($cachefile) && filemtime($cachefile) < filemtime($cachefile)) {  

          echo "<-- Cached paged --> Last modified: ".date("F d Y H:i:s.",filemtime($cachefile));
           include($cachefile);
           exit;
        }


     // start the output buffer
        ob_start();
```

Tried the above, seems to do nothing.

Comment: `filemtime($cachefile) < filemtime($cachefile)` what? This will ALWAYS be false...

Comment: Might i require a temp file from which to compare the values? Though im not certain how id acheive that.

Comment: Because you don't know if the database has changed without looking at the database, you will need to create a second query to check if new values have been added to the database and when they were last changed. You can check this against the modification time of the file. Hopefully you can optimise this query so that it will be quicker than just creating the page each time, but it's worth testing this.

Comment: You can stipulate a validity for you cache files and then it will become invalid when expires. Meanwhile, you can assume your cache is valid. If you modify your database in this mean time, you have to invalidate your cache file...